# Hibernate S1093 or 07009 Invalid parameter index

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am working with Hibernate 4.3 and Java 8 and Microsoft SQL 2014 (MSSQL).

I am trying to make a merge() of an entity with Hibernate.

```
public void actualizar(FactorUnidadMedida obj){
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(obj);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

When hibernate try to do commit() I get the following error:

Invalid parameter index 8.

I tried diferents version of Hibernate (4.3, 5.0) and drivers of JDBC(sqljdbc4.jar, jTDS.jar).

This is the log:

> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 Hibernate: update FactorUnidadMedida set estado=?, factor=?, fecha=?, usuario=? where idEmpresa=? and codUnidadDestino=? and codUnidadOrigen=?
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [AC]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [2] as [NUMERIC] - [0.01]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Wed Jul 20 15:09:25 COT 2016]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [ADMIN]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [MTR]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [1]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [CMS]
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07009
>
> 2016-07-20 15:09:35 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:129 - Invalid parameter index 8.

**Aditional information:**

The Entity have two composite-Foreing Keys.

```
package co.com.hermesWeb.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="FactorUnidadMedida")
@IdClass(FactorUnidadMedidaPK.class)
public class FactorUnidadMedida implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4123771692139896513L;

    @Id
    private int idEmpresa = 0;
    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idEmpresa", referencedColumnName="idEmpresa", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codUnidadOrigen", referencedColumnName="codigo", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private UnidadMedida unidadMedidaOrigen = null; 
    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idEmpresa", referencedColumnName="idEmpresa", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codUnidadDestino", referencedColumnName="codigo", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private UnidadMedida unidadMedidaDestino = null;
    private BigDecimal factor = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private String estado = "";
    private String usuario = "";
    private Date fecha = null;

    public int getIdEmpresa() {
        return idEmpresa;
    }
    public void setIdEmpresa(int idEmpresa) {
        this.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
    }
    public UnidadMedida getUnidadMedidaOrigen() {
        return unidadMedidaOrigen;
    }
    public void setUnidadMedidaOrigen(UnidadMedida unidadMedidaOrigen) {
        this.unidadMedidaOrigen = unidadMedidaOrigen;
    }
    public UnidadMedida getUnidadMedidaDestino() {
        return unidadMedidaDestino;
    }
    public void setUnidadMedidaDestino(UnidadMedida unidadMedidaDestino) {
        this.unidadMedidaDestino = unidadMedidaDestino;
    }
    public BigDecimal getFactor() {
        return factor;
    }
    public void setFactor(BigDecimal factor) {
        this.factor = factor;
    }
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

}
```

Note that [idEmpresa, codUnidadOrigen] and [idEmpresa, codUnidadDestino] are my foreing keys and the are using the same field [idEmpresa]. 
Some problem for that reason?

This is a data base table image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/87M6U.jpg

This is the complete stack with: log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ALL
https://gist.github.com/ferchoman09/45df8600de44eebc37a693e53a2bd391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the Model. I put both Froreing Keys wihout @Id in a separate fields.

```
package co.com.hermesWeb.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="FactorUnidadMedida")
@IdClass(FactorUnidadMedidaPK.class)
public class FactorUnidadMedida implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4123771692139896513L;

    @Id
    private int idEmpresa = 0;
    @Id
    private String codUnidadOrigen = "";
    @Id
    private String codUnidadDestino = "";

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idEmpresa", referencedColumnName="idEmpresa", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codUnidadOrigen", referencedColumnName="codigo", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private UnidadMedida unidadMedidaOrigen = null; 

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idEmpresa", referencedColumnName="idEmpresa", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="codUnidadDestino", referencedColumnName="codigo", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private UnidadMedida unidadMedidaDestino = null;
    private BigDecimal factor = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private String estado = "";
    private String usuario = "";
    private Date fecha = null;

    public int getIdEmpresa() {
        return idEmpresa;
    }
    public void setIdEmpresa(int idEmpresa) {
        this.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
    }
    public UnidadMedida getUnidadMedidaOrigen() {
        return unidadMedidaOrigen;
    }
    public UnidadMedida getUnidadMedidaDestino() {
        return unidadMedidaDestino;
    }
    public BigDecimal getFactor() {
        return factor;
    }
    public void setFactor(BigDecimal factor) {
        this.factor = factor;
    }
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
    public String getCodUnidadOrigen() {
        return codUnidadOrigen;
    }
    public void setCodUnidadOrigen(String codUnidadOrigen) {
        this.codUnidadOrigen = codUnidadOrigen;
    }
    public String getCodUnidadDestino() {
        return codUnidadDestino;
    }
    public void setCodUnidadDestino(String codUnidadDestino) {
        this.codUnidadDestino = codUnidadDestino;
    }

}
```